# How to remove magento root folder from site url?

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento. My site is http://neptun.al/new/. I need to remove magento root folder from the url. The required url must be http://neptun.al/

Here is a piece of code from .htaccess file

### you can put here your magento root folder

### path relative to web root

```
RewriteBase /new
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move Magento source from `new` directory to root directory and then change secure base url and unsecure base url in `core_config_data` to use `http://neptun.al`

Comment: i dont wanna move the sourse from the this "new" directory into the root

Answer (score 0):

You can also change it in your virtual hosts file

on debian

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Change you DocumentRoot in your host file

After that you need to run

```
a2ensite yourhostfile

service apache2 reload
```